# What for is the direct_front_name tag in Magento

Tags: magento, config

Some modules have a `<request><direct_front_name>...</direct_front_name></request>` in their module config, for example `xmlconnect` and `api`. What is this tag for?

**What I think it is for:**
`xmlconnect` and `api` are both used as direct entry points for the site (as opposed normal modules which are reached mostly from within the site). So in combination with the option to use store codes in your store urls you can specify a direct_front_end tag to make the store code not necessary for those modules. This way there is no 404 when calling them without a store code.

(Kind of answered it myself, but couldn't find any information about it online. Might be of use to others. And maybe anyone has something to add.)

Comment: Do you mean `direct_front_name`?

Comment: You're right, excuse me. Edited it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're totally right. And the php DOC clearly tells so :

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::isDirectAccessFrontendName() :

/**
     * Check if code declared as direct access frontend name
     * this mean what this url can be used without store code
     *
     * @param   string $code
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function isDirectAccessFrontendName($code)
```